# Non-permanent way to cap a clay cleanout pipe

Tags: plumbing, mosquitoes

I have a clay cleanout pipe, with bell, in my side yard. There is no type of cover and I want to prevent mosquitoes from breeding inside.  Does anyone know of a way I can cover it while still allowing periodic access and not damaging the pipe in anyway?  I've looked online and at Lowe's for rubber caps but nothing fits the exterior 9.25"-9.5" perimeter.

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 1):

A big stone is very good. Or, a 12x12 or small concrete paver from the store will also work great. Or, you may find smaller metal (you need UV proof) trash can lids at the store. A rock can go on top of the lid or a rock can be attached or hung from the lid inside the pipe. Or, you can get some concrete or cement mix & make your own custom cap.

Comment: Would a concrete paver provide enough of a seal to keep mosquitoes out?  They can fit through very small places.

Comment: It depends on how flat the pipe is, but yes if they match. But, you could caulk the paver down or put a thin weather-stripping on the pipe's end to create a perfect seal. A snug fitting plastic lid from a coffee container or gallon bucket or a cut-down bucket. Really whatever works, the paver would just be the paperweight & won't care about wind, UV rays or weather.